# Is there a simple way to export posts from a facebook fan page to an external website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So facebook has the social plug ins which allow content from outside facebook get into facebook. However if one wanted to use updates made to a facebook page to update an external website at the same time are there similar plug ins or applications that allow this? Otherwise how would one start out building this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every facebook fan page has rss file which is written in xml.
So if you have time to code you need to parse this file when you need posts from facebook and show them as you like with some css and html tag.
http://www.kristi-barrow.com/facebook-rss-feeds-what-is-available/

Else you go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ and put the link of your page and you'll get a code that show stream in your site!

Comment: I don't think the RSS feed is included any more. Scumbag facebook. :(